# Survivor game probability

Tags: probability, self-study

In particular, suppose that the probability of winning the immunity
challenge when Rich chooses continue is $x$ for Rich, $y$ for Kelly, and  $1 - x - y $ for Rudy; similarly, the probability of winning when Rich chooses Give Up
is $z$ for Kelly and  $ 1 - z$ for Rudy.

Further, suppose that Rich's chance of
being picked by the jury is $p$ if he has won immunity and has voted off Rudy;
his chance of being picked is $q$ if Kelly has won immunity and has voted off
Rudy. continue to assume that, if Rudy wins immunity, he keeps Rich with
probability $1$, and that

How can i write expressions entailing the general probabilities $(P,q,x,y)$ that summarize these two conditions.

1. Kelly is very likely to win the immunity challenge once Rich
   gives up and
2. Rich wins the jury's final vote more often when Kelly
   has voted out Rudy than when Rich has done so.

Suppose that above two conditions hold. Prove that Rich's optimal
strategy is Give UP.

Following is image attached, but here instead of actual values we are supposing probabilities in form of $x,y,z$

[image]

Comment: I am not understanding how can i write `very likely probability`, Probability of Kelly wining immunity when Rich give up is $z$. How can i write `Kelly is very likely to win the immunity challenge once Rich gives up`. Maybe by assuming probability more than 50%

Comment: @Xi'an whole story line up is this. This is extra details that's why i did not added it in question. In the summer of 2000, CBS television broadcast the first of the series of Survivor shows, which became an instant hit and helped launch the whole new genre of "reality TV. We pick up the story when just three contestants were left: Rudy, Kelly, and Rich. Of them, Rudy was the oldest contestant, an honest and blunt person who was very popular with the contestants who had been previously voted off.

Comment: It was generally agreed that, if he was one of the last two, then he would be voted the million-dollar winner. So it was in the interests of both Kelly and Rich that they should face each other, rather than face Rudy, in the final vote. But neither wanted to be seen as instrumental in voting off Rudy. With just three contestants left, the winner of the immunity challenge is effectively decisive in the cast-offvote, because the other two must vote against each other.

Comment: Thus the jury would know who was responsible for voting off Rudy and, given his popularity, would regard the act of voting him off with disfavor. The person doing so would harm his or her chances in the final vote. This was especially a problem for Rich, because he was known to have an alliance with Rudy.